# React Native modal in iOS

Tags: ios, modal-dialog, react-native

Here guys, I want use a modal to show some views, but at the same time user may occur another custom alert which i wrap it use modal too. it works fine in android but in iOS, it shows me like this
 `Warning: Attempt to present <RCTModalHostViewController: 0x7b069310>  on <UIViewController: 0x7ae2c1a0> which is already presenting <RCTModalHostViewController: 0x7b4fa9d0>`

any solutions?

Comment: Can you check to see if a model is already being shown (i.e. set a flag when showing a modal), and if one is already visible, cancel it before showing the next one?

Comment: actually i know what the warning mean, just is there a way to show a modal when another modal is shown? it's fine in android but no iOS.

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: just a modal has another modal view as its child. i have test it in RN 27 and it works fine.Thanks buddies

Comment: Hi @liupluto, how did you fix this problem? I have the same problem only on IOS